Property does not exist on type even though defined in amplify gen 2 backend
const Post = ({
  post,
  onDelete,
  isSignedIn,
}: {
  post: Schema["Post"];
  onDelete: (id: string) => void;
  isSignedIn: boolean;
}) => {
const router = useRouter();
const onDetail = () => {
    router.push(`posts/${(post as Schema["Post"]).id}`);
};
  return (
    <div className="border bg-gray-100 w-full p-4 rounded flex justify-between ">
    <button onClick={onDetail}>
        <div className="flex gap-2">
            <div>Title:</div>
            <div>{post.title}</div>
        </div>
    </button>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value={post.id} />
      {isSignedIn ? (
        <button
          className="text-red-500 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => onDelete(post.id)}
        >
          X
        </button>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;

const schema = a.schema({
  Post: a
    .model({
      id : a.id(),
      title: a.string().required(),
      comments: a.hasMany("Comment", "postId"),
      owner: a.string().authorization(allow=>[allow.owner().to(["read", "delete"])]),
    })
    .authorization(allow => [allow.publicApiKey().to(["read"]), allow.owner()]),
  Comment: a
    .model({
      id: a.id(),
      postId: a.id(),
      content: a.string().required(),
      post: a.belongsTo("Post", "postId"),
      owner: a.string().authorization(allow => [allow.owner().to(["read", "delete"])]),
    })
    .authorization(allow => [allow.publicApiKey().to(["read"]), allow.owner()]),
});

Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ type: { title: string; comments: GetRelationshipRef<InjectImplicitModelFields<FieldTypes<ModelTypes<{ Post: ModelType<SetTypeSubArg<{ fields: { id: ModelField<Nullable, never, undefined>; title: ModelField<string, "required", undefined>; comments: ModelRelationalField<...>; owner: ModelField<...>; }; ident...'
also getting
this Property 'type' is missing in type '{ readonly id: Nullable | undefined; readonly title: string; }' but required in type '{ type: { title: string; comments: GetRelationshipRef<InjectImplicitModelFields<FieldTypes<ModelTypes<{ Post: ModelType<SetTypeSubArg<{ fields: { id: ModelField<Nullable, never, undefined>; title: ModelField<string, "required", undefined>; comments: ModelRelationalField<...>; owner: ModelField<...>; }; ident...'.ts(2741)
ClientSchema.d.ts(27, 9): 'type' is declared here. this is troubling as well in another part of the code.
Not sure what to try... suggestions by both gpt and copilot doesnt work :)

As you can see in your error message the type is nested inside a property called 'type'. So the correct way to access types for Schemas using ampliy gen 2 using your example is: Schema["Post"]["type"] instead of Schema["Post"]. This is also in the documentation as well.
